# Microsoft SQL Server Like keyword

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, collation

Any inputs on making Like keyword in Microsoft SQL server act as Case-sensitive.

For example : Name Like 'David' gets all the names David or david or daVid etc.
My goal is to get only David.I am interested in knowing different ways from the experts.

Comment: How is the data being stored? Which DBMS?

Comment: Have you tried my solution using SQL Colation?

Comment: _"HOW TO DO IT USING SUBSTRING?"_ >> that's a different question you added later, you may want to ask that separately, but a Google search gives you a zillion answers ;).

Answer (score 4):

You need to use collation.

```
SELECT * FROM myTable  
WHERE LastName COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS = 'smyTH'
```

Comment: @karthikgorijavolu - To do it via a substring you can add the following replace the WHERE clause to the following:

WHERE SUBSTRING(LastName,1,5) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS = 'smyTH'

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example using `Darren Davis`s answer

```
declare @tmp table (LastName nvarchar(10))

insert @tmp
select ('Gorijavolu')

select  LastName As 'CorrectCase' from  @tmp WHERE SUBSTRING(LastName,1,4) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS = 'Gori'
select  LastName AS 'WrongCase' from    @tmp WHERE SUBSTRING(LastName,1,4) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS = 'gori'
```

Gives:

```
CorrectCase
-----------
Gorijavolu
(1 row(s) affected)

WrongCase
----------

(0 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what database you are using. For example, MySQL compares case-insensitively if you choose a case-insensitive collation for the table or database, and case-sensitively otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

`LIKE` [in PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-matching.html) is case-sensitive while `ILIKE` is case-insensitive. So this varies along what DBMS you're using.